# Database - Enumeration type - Extra table or just a column

Tags: java, sql, database-design, foreign-keys

Suppose I have a Person entity with a status associated with it

status can be *ACTIVE/INACTIVE/BLOCKED*

Which table design would be better ?

Just one table

`Person(id, name, status)`

Or
Two tables with a foreign key reference from Person to Status table.

`Person(id, name, status_id)`

`Status(id, name)`

It is much easier to manage the implementation with just one Person table. But do anyone see any future problems associated with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem having a single table, although I would recommend a `check` constraint to validate the value:

```
check (status in ('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE', 'BLOCKED'))
```

There are many situations when you want a reference table.  It provides a lot of capabilities, such as:

- Easily able to add new statuses.
- Easily able to change the names.
- The ability to have short and long names.
- The ability to share the *exact same* statuses across different tables.
- The ability to know when a new a status was added or changed.
- The ability to include priorities or ordering for the statuses.

However, it is not necessary to put all strings into a reference table.